# couldn't use "options single-request" in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, glibc, resolve

Write parameter 'options single-request' in /etc/resolv.conf, the font become red.Red means this parameter has a syntax error, but i don't know where am i wrong. My /etc/resolv.conf as below:
`options single-request`
`nameserver 10.11.199.119`

Answer (score 2):

> Red means this parameter has a syntax error

No, it doesn't.

It means that whatever editor you are using doesn't understand that syntax. But what actually matters is whether your GLIBC understands that syntax (GLIBC >= 2.10 should, according to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)).

> My glibc is 2.17. So why system didn't understand "options single-request"?

There is no such thing as "system" here.

The `/etc/resolv.conf` is just a text file, it doesn't "understand" anything. You can edit that text file using a variety of editors: `vi`, `gvim`, `emacs`, or no editor at all (you can use `echo` or `cat` to create that file).

Now, a *particular* editor you used (but didn't tell us what that editor is), pretends to understand the file syntax, performs syntax highlighting, and even highlights "mistakes" in red. But that particular editor has simply not been updated when the new GLIBC syntax was implemented. The GLIBC developers all use `vi` or `emacs`, and probably don't even know that that editor exists.

So when you say "why did the system not understand ...", what you are really asking is "why haven't the developers of that editor that you are using updated it to understand ...". There could be a few reasons for that: they may not know about the new syntax, or they may have abandoned that editor, or they may have already fixed it but the fix hasn't been included in your OS release.

Comment: as you see, my system is: centos 7.1.1503, glibc version is（use command “rpm -qi glibc”） :2.17. Obviously my glibc version is newer than 2.10. So why system didn't understand "options single-request".

Comment: I use <code>vi</code> to add the parameters <code>options single-request</code> in resolv.conf then become red highlight. But if i add the parameters such as <code>options timeout:5</code>, there is no highlight. So i guess my  parameters <code>options single-request</code> is didn't understand by system.

Comment: As @Employed Russian has mentioned, the red highlight is displayed in vim/vi because the syntax highlight file for the resolv.conf file does not have a *definition* for `options single-request`. 

However, if you refer to the [man page for resolve.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html), you will see that `options single-request` is very much valid.

Therefore, you need not be concerned about the red syntax highlighting in vim. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it has to be:

options single-request-reopen

?